# Error using toString() with EditText

Tags: java, android

Using this line to get the text in an EditText field to get the string to translate

`texttotranslate = (String) txtText.toString();`

I get errors of this type:

`09-15 15:20:13.311: E/ATTN:(27603): android.widget.EditText{421dbeb8 VFED..CL .F...... 0,190-720,260 #7f0b0029 app:id/txtText}- your input`

where

"(27603): android.widget.EditText{421dbeb8 VFED..CL .F...... 0,190-720,260 #7f0b0029 app:id/txtText"

is the value found in texttotranslate.  The actual input was supposed to be the word "yes".

Has anyone seen errors of this type?
Am I using toString() incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`getText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()) method

> Return the text the TextView is displaying.

```
texttotranslate = txtText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

In java you need to use the getter method `getText()` to get the text property, like this:

```
(String)txtText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Instead of copying for others, can you explain your answer?

Comment: Sorry, in java you need to use the getter method getText() to get the text property...